# Radio light/radio wave light: what does this mean?

Tags: electromagnetism, visible-light, electromagnetic-radiation, radio

What is **radio light** and **radio wave light**? Is this a term? There is nothing on the internet that goes by this. I need an explanation as to what this term means and why my professor keeps using it.

Example of something she said to me in discussion on Hertz/Maxwell: I talked about the idea that any time electrons or magnets are moved around, they generate light (often **radio light**)?  Hertz was working with these same concepts.  He used a device that forced electricity to move back and forth at a regular rate, which created **radio wave light**.  Then he used another device that allowed him to see electrical currents (moving electrons) responding to that same  light, so he could show that it was really there. The important stuff is understanding that the experiment involved creating and detecting **radio light** using electrical circuits.

I would just like to understand better what she is trying to say.

Comment: "Radio light" is just radio waves. They are interchangeable because light is also an electromagnetic wave (though "radio light" is definitely non-standard terminology).

Comment: Thus is an amended version of previously closed questions https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/396734/36194

Answer (score 1):

From the context it is clear that your professor means with the rather idiosyncratic terms "radio light" or "radio wave light" actually "electromagnetic waves" in the frequency range of those used for radio transmissions. Also light waves are electromagnetic waves but with much higher frequencies than radio waves. To call radio waves "light" is rather unusual.